# C++: calling main() twice leads to infinite loop recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static int v = 5;
    cout<<v;
    v--;
    if(v)
    {
        main();
        main();
    }
}
```

If I call the main just once the code behaves properly and gives the output `54321` but if I compile the above program it gives as infinite loop and then segmentation fault occurs. can anyone please explain?

Comment: *If I call the main just once the code behaves properly* -- This code has undefined behavior.  You cannot call `main` in a C++ program, not even once.

Comment: But undefined behavior aside, if you step through with your debugger you'll see the issue.

Comment: Actually, it's not undefined behaviour.   Calling `main()` is actually forbidden by every version of the C++ standard, with a statement worded as "The function `main` shall not be used within a program" where "used" (by definition) covers calling it, taking its address, and other things.   The word "shall" means the rule is mandatory and, if a program violates that rule, the implementation is required to issue a diagnostic.   Sadly, quite a few real-world implementations do not comply with this requirement of the standard.

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler?

Comment: Read also [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (some C++ standard) or some equivalent thing. And [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And read [a good book on C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Comment: @Peter So it "shall" not be used. So what happens if is? Is this not the definition of undefined behavior. The standard does not define a meaning to the behavior of calling `main()` because you "shall" not call it.

Comment: @Peter See: Section 3.27: [defns.undefined] undefined behavior: **when a program uses an erroneous construct** I would classify using "main()" when the standards I should not as "erroneous construct". But if that does not satisfy I would fall back on **when this document omits any explicit definition** as there is no definition of what to do when you call "main()" as you shall not do it.

Comment: @Peter Alternatively we can use section 3.11: [defns.ill.formed] ill-formed program: **program that is not well-formed**. See section 3.29: [[defns.well.formed]] well-formed program: **C++ program constructed according ...  diagnosable semantic rules**  Which leads us to your section 4.1 [intro.compliance] Implementation compliance paragraph 2.1 **If a program contains no violations**.

Comment: @Peter So a program contain a call to "main()" is in vilolation 4.1 paragraph 2.1 which means it dignosable semantic rules have been violated which means it is not well-formed which means it is ill-formed which means the standard does not define how the program should run. Which means the program has no definition (or is undefined).

Comment: @MartinYork - Undefined behaviour means that the standard does not impose any constraints on what happens. A statement that a program shall not do something (in this case, use of `main()`) is a constraint. If a program violates such a constraint, then it is ill-formed. An implementation which does not diagnose that is not compliant. Trying to explain the behaviour of an ill-formed program that is not diagnosed by a non-compliant implementation is academic, except in context of a particular compiler/version. But it is still not undefined behaviour, since the standard described a constraint.

Comment: Incidentally, if we were to do this in C (use C I/O instead of C++ IO, remove the `using`) then the program is well-formed.   The C standard does not disallow calling of `main()`.   And, in that case, the program is infinitely recursive.   The behaviour is then undefined, since eventually `v` will underflow (reach minimum value that an `int` can represent, then decrement it) or exceed available stack (whichever comes first).

Comment: @Peter There are two types of program. well-formed and ill-formed. The standard defines the behavior of well-formed programs (apart from a few documented implementation defined instances). The compilation of ill-formed programs is is not defined and thus the program has undefined behavior. These three definitions are all part of the standard in section 3. [intro.defs] **Terms and definitions**. Calling `main()` from a program breaks diagnosable semantic rules (the shall you mentioned). Thus the program is ill-formed and thus by definition displays undefined behavior.

Comment: @Peter Whether the compiler is conformant is irrelevant. We are talking about about what we expect assuming a conformant compiler. No compiler is truly 100% conformant (if we had to take the compiler into account we could never have a discussion about behavior of a program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `if` statement, any *non-zero* value is evaluated as true.

The 1st call will run a recursive loop, starting with `v=5`, decrementing `v` to `4` before the first `if`, and then continuing to decrement `v` on each iteration until `v` becomes 0, breaking the loop.

The 2nd call will run a new recursive loop, starting with `v=0`, decrementing `v` to `-1` before the first `if`, and then continuing to decrement `v` on each iteration until `v` overflows and *eventually* becomes 0 again, breaking the loop.

If it even gets far, since each call to `main()` pushes data on the call stack, recursively, until there is no more stack space available.

Comment: You missed the main issue. Calling main() from another function is undefined behavior. Thus the code can do anything.